# django use Pk field in a url

Tags: django

I have created a pk field(not automatically created by the model).
when I want to use this pk name(in my case school_id) I got this error:

```
Generic detail view SchoolDetailView must be called with either an object pk or a slug.
```

although I am using the correct pk name(school_pk) I have used in my model in the url.
my code is as follows:
models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
class School(models.Model):
    school_pk = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    principal = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("basic_app:school_detail",kwargs={'school_pk':self.school_pk})
```

views.py:

```
class SchoolListView(ListView):

    model = models.School
    template_name = 'basic_app/school_list.html'


class SchoolDetailView(DetailView):
    context_object_name = 'school'
    model = models.School
    template_name = 'basic_app/school_detail.html'
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
path('',views.SchoolListView.as_view(),name='school_list'),
path('<int:school_pk>/',views.SchoolDetailView.as_view(),name='school_detail'),]
```

when I try to go to school_detail page by going to http://127.0.0.1:8000/basic_app/1/  for example
I have this error:

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/basic_app/1/
Django Version: 2.0
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
Generic detail view SchoolDetailView must be called with either an object pk or a slug.
```

I have tried to use get_object and/or get_queryset but I believe I am doing it the wrong way. if any one can help that will be great and highly appreciated. Thanks.
note:I dont want to omit school_pk field from my model and use PK that is automatically genertaed).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `pk_url_kwarg = 'school_pk'` to view `SchoolDetailView`. By default it is set to `pk`.

```
class SchoolDetailView(DetailView):
    context_object_name = 'school'
    model = models.School
    template_name = 'basic_app/school_detail.html'
    pk_url_kwarg = 'school_pk'
```

Comment: ... finallllllly ..you are my hero...thanks a lot ..it worked...I really appreciated..I was stuck here for a day

Comment: @WISAM welcome.  check UML diagram of `DetailView` http://epydoc.pythondiary.com/generic-views/uml_class_diagram_for_django_v_28.gif  for extra information

Comment: another question please later I have another table(student)..the url for detail view(students in each school) is:`path('<int:school_pk>/student/<int:student_pk>/',views.StudentDetailView.as_view(),name='student_detail'),` . in this case I have two pk in the url. do u know how to solve this since i have to include school_id in `def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("basic_app:student_detail",kwargs={'student_pk':self.student_pk})` and set pk_url_kwarg for both school_id and student_id?

Comment: @WISAM override `get_object` method

Comment: @ Anjaneyulu Batta  I am trying to use get_object..but appearntly I am not doing it the right way.. because I am still having errors